# How to calculate new cursor position given start position, angle and distance

Tags: c#

I'm writing a class to help with mouse movement and I can't seem to get the move with distance and angle function to work properly, it always seems to move the mouse in a 45 degree angle.

```
public static POINT moveDistanceAngle(POINT start, double distance, double angle)
{
    double radians = angleToRadians(angle);
    int x = (int)Math.Round(Math.Cos(radians) * distance);
    int y = (int)Math.Round(Math.Sin(radians) * distance);

    return new POINT(start.X + x, start.Y + y);
}
```

I'm using GetCursorPos to get the point.

```
public static double angleToRadians(double angle)
{
    return (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
}
```

Have I done something wrong with the maths?

Comment: Looks fine at first glance. You could try making the 180 explicitly a double by making it 180.0, but that should already be OK since Math.PI will be a double. Can you debug this and check the values of radians, x and y all look correct? Either set breakpoints and step through or log out the values as you go. Is the angle input parameter definitely correct?

Comment: The math looks right.  Can you post your definition of `POINT` and maybe some calling code that exhibits the incorrect result?

Comment: FYI, the `System.Drawing` namespace already has a `Point` struct you could use.

Comment: Please show the input, expected output, and actual output so we can see what problem you're encountering.

Comment: @RufusL The point structure in system drawing was what i was using before but I read that the structure can cause issues because the order of variables can change or something like that?

Comment: I don't think so? It's mutable, if you prefer immutability, but otherwise I don't know of any issues with it. Can you link us to what you've read about it? (after you've posted more details of the problem here)

Comment: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getcursorpos - note the comment in c# section

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for this dumb post. After spending hours on it I figured out the actual issue was in my maths to set the mouse cursor and not in the maths. This post actually has the right maths.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like *angle* has measured in radians not degrees and you make double conversion to radians::

```
public static POINT moveDistanceAngle(POINT start, double distance, double angleRad)
{
    int x = (int)Math.Round(Math.Cos(angleRad) * distance);
    int y = (int)Math.Round(Math.Sin(angleRad) * distance);

    return new POINT(start.X + x, start.Y + y);
}
```

Comment: That might be true, but I don't see how you can guess that from the question.

Comment: Try emulate this case by set *double radians = angleToRadians(angleToRadians(angle));* and make several tests on these input params: [(10,10), 10, 90], [(10,10), 10, 180], [(10,10), 10, 270].